# My input is not defined

Tags: python

```
import os, sys
def main():    
    pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    os.chdir(pathname)
    codObj=[]                                                         
    archivo = input("Ingrese el nombre del archivo: ")
```

This is my error:

```
NameError: name 'FIBO' is not defined
```

Comment: Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` assuming you are using python 2.x

Comment: Is that really the error message you get when you use `input` instead of `raw_input`?

Comment: wooh 3 secs, wth 0.o

Comment: You got your answer.   What difference does it make?